# reload mat-table after custom filter

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to filter my mat-table in two differents ways, its by name, using filterPredicate, it works fine, and filter by state, where I use filteredData:

```js
displayedColumns = ['type', 'name'];
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA);
this.dataSource.filterPredicate =
    (data: Element, filter: string) => (data.name.indexOf(filter) != -1);


applyFilterByName(filterValue: string) {
    filterValue = filterValue.trim(); // Remove whitespace
    filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); // MatTableDataSource defaults to lowercase matches
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
}
    }

applyFilterByType(filterValue: number) {
    this.dataSource.filteredData =
        this.dataSource.filteredData.filter(data =>
            data.type. !== filterValue))
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [
    { type: 2, name: 'Hydrogen' },
    { type: 2, name: 'Helium' },
    { type: 3, name: 'Lithium' },
    { type: 2, name: 'Beryllium' },
    { type: 5, name: 'Boron' }
];
```

My problem is with applyFilterByType, I can see in console, that "this.dataSource.filteredData" as the correct values but my table is no reload, how can I force to reload with this data?

Comment: Can you post your html as well?

Answer (score -1):

Try to combine filters by $ symbol:

```
private nameFilterValue: string;
private typeFilterValue: string;

applyFilterByName(filterValue: string) {
  this.nameFilterValue = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  this.dataSource.filter = !!this.typeFilterValue ? `${this.typeFilterValue}$${this.nameFilterValue}` : this.nameFilterValue;
}

applyFilterByType(filterValue: number) {
  this.typeFilterValue = filterValue.toString().toLowerCase();
  this.dataSource.filter = !!this.nameFilterValue ? `${this.typeFilterValue}$${this.nameFilterValue}` : this.typeFilterValue;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but my problem is reload the table, not the filtering

Comment: If I am not mistaken, Your primary goal is data filtration by multiple criteria. Reloading of table will be workaround